# Example of Constant Morphism

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am reading Basic Theory of Elliptic Curves, there I came about a statement saying :

A Morphism of curves is either Surjective or Constant.

While studying Isogenes I came across examples of Surjective morphism but I am still wondering for an example of Constant morphism.

Comment: Well, they are just that ... constant

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I didn't understand ? A morphism is a Rational map defined on all points!! Do you want to say  (x,y,z)----> (a,b,c) where a,b,c are constant !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_1, E_2$ be elliptic curves. Fix a point $Q \in E_2$. Then the map $\phi : E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ defined by $P \mapsto Q$ is a constant morphism.

This is because it is a rational map (it is just effectively a constant polynomial) and is defined everywhere trivially.